# How to configure pycharm with odoo running in docker

Tags: docker, pycharm, odoo

I have found how to configure pycharm to debug odoo, but for odoo that running in docker (my system is ubuntu 18 system), i can't configure pycharm to debug odoo container.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into [Pycharm Remote Debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html)?

Comment: but i need to debugg odoo container, i don't have odoo installed in laptop, i have just odoo container.

Comment: What do you think REMOTE Debugging is for?

Comment: for example edit module  by pycharm, then execut run in pycharm to run odoo container and show errors in pycharm....like this: 
Debug Odoo 10 using Pycharm IDE in Ubuntu [ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O7OdXcYCo3o ]

Comment: good one. See my updated answer, there is another tool that not only allows debugging but provides a shell to perform some operation while you debug session is running. https://github.com/Kozea/wdb#docker

Answer (score 1):

> AS you said in the comment, I assume that your addons/custom_addons are in the folder attached to your container via volume mapping.

You can simply run the following command to get logs of the 'odoo_container' as

`docker logs -f odoo_container`

replace 'odoo_container' with your container's name.

OR

if you have configured logs directory and mapped with container's log directory like given below in docker-compose file / in your docker run command,

`./logs:/var/log/odoo`

then, you can run the command like

`tail -f logs/odoo-server.log`

It will print the console log output from either container or logs file mapped via volume to the container.

Hope this helps.

========================

Recently I have started using this tool

> https://github.com/Kozea/wdb#docker

That also comes with a docker setup with Odoo container. It is superb and easy. This not only provides you the debugging but also allows you to do some operation just like python's inbuilt shell. I still use the 'tail' command to see the logs stored as a bound volume so I can go back and check the errors / bad queries / anything that is failing.